# Shadow over element with background image?

Tags: css

In the following example I have two elements. One has a background image for the content section and the other does not.  Both headers have a `box-shadow` property.  How can I make the shadow visible above the element with the background image set?

```css
.testcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 120px;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

#hasbgimage {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x100");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with no image</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with image</div>
  <div class="content" id="hasbgimage"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply add `z-index` to the first element to make it above with its `box-shadow` also

```css
.testcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 120px;
}

.header {
  position:relative; /*And don't forget this !!!*/
  z-index:2;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

#hasbgimage {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x100");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with no image</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with image</div>
  <div class="content" id="hasbgimage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this before posting. Obviously it works in the simplified example here, but for some reason it did not work in my project.  This is why I have accepted the other answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @ScottBeeson maybe because you forget to add positon:relative ;) .. but the way you need to see why it's not working, it's important to find the issue then using another method to avoid the issue ;)

Comment: You are right. I added `position: relative` to the header and the z-index now fixes it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define **inset** shadow for `#hasbgimage`

```css
.testcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 120px;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

#hasbgimage {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x100");
  background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with no image</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with image</div>
  <div class="content" id="hasbgimage"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a child div and set your background image on it instead, so it is not overriding the box shadow.

```css
.testcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 120px;
}

.header {
  position:relative; /*And don't forget this !!!*/
  z-index:2;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}

#hasbgimage {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x100/aabbcc/");
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with no image</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="testcontainer">
  <div class="header">test with image</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div  id="hasbgimage"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that. It obviously creates a gap. I added a negative top margin to offset and now it looks exactly like it did before; no visible shadow.

Comment: I added a code snippet of my approach so you can see that it works.